# spinner wont appear on the form

Tags: canvas, colors, spinner, visible

hi guys I've made a boo boo!
I made a spinner and populated it, then thought... i'd like to change the colour of the form from black to white, so i did but now the spinner isnt there and im not sure what ive done! well I kind of do, I figured I have the code in the wrong place but I'm not sure where the right place is... sooooo

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
import sys, traceback
import re
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
root = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
        # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size''')
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):

#add drop down box filled with stations
        spinner = Spinner(
# default value shown
        text='Pick a Station',
        values=('Appledore','Axminster','Bampton','Barnstaple','Bere Alston','Bideford','Bovey Tracey','Braunton','Bridgwater','Brixham','Buckfastleigh','Budleigh Salterton','Burnham on sea','Camels Head','Castle Cary','Chagford','Chard','Cheddar','Chulmleigh','Colyton','Combe Martin','Crediton','Crewkerne','Crownhill','Cullompton','Dartmouth','Dawlish','Exeter Danes Castle','Exeter Middlemoor','Exmouth','Frome','Glastonbury','Greenbank','Hartland','Hatherleigh','Holsworthy','Honiton','Ilfracombe','Ilminster','Ivybridge','Kingsbridge','Kingston','Lundy Island','Lynton','Martock','Minehead','Modbury','Moretonhampstead','Nether Stowey','Newton Abbot','North Tawton','Okehampton','Ottery St Mary','Paignton','Plympton','Plymstock','Porlock','Princetown','Salcombe','Seaton','Shepton Mallet','Sidmouth','Somerton','South Molton','Street','Taunton','Tavistock','Teignmouth','Tiverton','Topsham','Torquay','Torrington','Totnes','USAR','Wellington','Wells','Williton','Wincanton','Witheridge','Wiveliscombe','Woolacombe','Yelverton','Yeovil'),
# just for positioning in our example
        size_hint=(None, None),
        size=(100, 44),
        pos_hint={'center_y': 0.8})
        def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
            print('The spinner', spinner, 'have text', text)
            spinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
            runTouchApp(spinner)
        return root
###########################
#load stations into a list
StationsString = "Appledore,Axminster,Bampton,Barnstaple,Bere Alston,Bideford,Bovey Tracey,Braunton,Bridgwater,Brixham,Buckfastleigh,Budleigh Salterton,Burnham on sea,Camels Head,Castle Cary,Chagford,Chard,Cheddar,Chulmleigh,Colyton,Combe Martin,Crediton,Crewkerne,Crownhill,Cullompton,Dartmouth,Dawlish,Exeter Danes Castle,Exeter Middlemoor,Exmouth,Frome,Glastonbury,Greenbank,Hartland,Hatherleigh,Holsworthy,Honiton,Ilfracombe,Ilminster,Ivybridge,Kingsbridge,Kingston,Lundy Island,Lynton,Martock,Minehead,Modbury,Moretonhampstead,Nether Stowey,Newton Abbot,North Tawton,Okehampton,Ottery St Mary,Paignton,Plympton,Plymstock,Porlock,Princetown,Salcombe,Seaton,Shepton Mallet,Sidmouth,Somerton,South Molton,Street,Taunton,Tavistock,Teignmouth,Tiverton,Topsham,Torquay,Torrington,Totnes,USAR,Wellington,Wells,Williton,Wincanton,Witheridge,Wiveliscombe,Woolacombe,Yelverton,Yeovil"
TheStation = StationsString.split(',')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()



###########################
#get info for incident
def FindIncident( sStation ):
    webpage = request.urlopen("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35")#main page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
    incidents = soup.find(id="CollapsiblePanel1") #gets todays incidents panel
    Links = [] #create list call Links

    for line in incidents.find_all('a'): #get all hyperlinks
        Links.append("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/"+line.get('href')) #loads links into Links list while making them full links
    n = 0
    e = len(Links)
    if e == n: #if no links available no need to continue
       print("No Incidents Found Please Try Later")
       sys.exit(0)

    sFound = False
    while n < e: #loop through links to find station
        if sFound: #if the station has been found stop looking
            sys.exit(0)
        webpage = request.urlopen(Links[n]) #opens link in list)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage) #loads webpage
        if soup.find_all('p', text=re.compile(r'{}'.format(sStation))) == []:#check if returned value is found
            #do nothing leaving blank gave error
            a = "1" #this is pointless but stops the error
        else:
            print(soup.find_all('p', text=re.compile(r'{}'.format(sStation)))) #output result
            WebLink = Links[n]
            sFound = True # to avoid un needed goes through the loop process
         n=n+1 # moves counter to next in list
    if not sFound: #after looping process if nothing has been found output nothing found
        print("nothing found please try again later")
    return;
###########################
```

Thats the whole thing so far, im going to ass a button under the spinner that calls the FindIncident with the station selected in the spinner, under the button is going to be a label to send te details to (instead of print)
and im hoping to have another button under that which only appears if the station was found to open the url in a web page.

Thats all just fyi to be clear lol my question is where do i put the code for the spinner to be visible?

Thanks
Raif

Comment: when i get rid of the colour aspect of the code the spinner appears, or is there but as soon as i change the colour to white its gone. I've even tried # define color 1 as black on blue
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
stdscr.bkgd(' ', curses.color_pair(1))... ideas please

Answer (score 0):

I started from scratch on the form, didn't realise you have to add widgets to the parent widget

```
class DSFRSapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        i = Image(source='DSFRSLogo.png',
                  allow_stretch=True,
                  pos_hint = ({'center_x':0.5, 'y': .25}))
        spinner = Spinner(
text='Pick a Station',
values=('Appledore','Axminster','Bampton','Barnstaple','Bere Alston','Bideford','Bovey Tracey','Braunton','Bridgwater','Brixham','Buckfastleigh','Budleigh Salterton','Burnham on sea','Camels Head','Castle Cary','Chagford','Chard','Cheddar','Chulmleigh','Colyton','Combe Martin','Crediton','Crewkerne','Crownhill','Cullompton','Dartmouth','Dawlish','Exeter Danes Castle','Exeter Middlemoor','Exmouth','Frome','Glastonbury','Greenbank','Hartland','Hatherleigh','Holsworthy','Honiton','Ilfracombe','Ilminster','Ivybridge','Kingsbridge','Kingston','Lundy Island','Lynton','Martock','Minehead','Modbury','Moretonhampstead','Nether Stowey','Newton Abbot','North Tawton','Okehampton','Ottery St Mary','Paignton','Plympton','Plymstock','Porlock','Princetown','Salcombe','Seaton','Shepton Mallet','Sidmouth','Somerton','South Molton','Street','Taunton','Tavistock','Teignmouth','Tiverton','Topsham','Torquay','Torrington','Totnes','USAR','Wellington','Wells','Williton','Wincanton','Witheridge','Wiveliscombe','Woolacombe','Yelverton','Yeovil'),
size_hint=(None, None),
size=(150, 44),
pos_hint = ({'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.35}))
        b = Button(text="Search For Incidents",size_hint=(None, None),
                   pos_hint =({'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.25}),
                   size=(150, 44))
        LblRes = Label(text="Results will display here",
                       pos_hint =({'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.15}),
                       size_hint=(600,100),color=(1,1,1,1),font_size=35)
        b.bind(on_press=FindIncident(Spinner.text))
        self.root.add_widget(spinner)
        self.root.add_widget(LblRes)
        self.root.add_widget(i)
        self.root.add_widget(b)
        return
```